# GROUP BY all columns syntax

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, null, group-by, oracle12c

In Oracle database, to specify one single group of all data

```
SELECT sum(price)
FROM tabA
GROUP BY ()
```

I understand that `GROUP BY` clause can be omitted here, but if we include explicitly, would the full form be `GROUP BY ()` ? This is taken from [GROUPING SETS](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14223/aggreg.htm#i1006842)'s documentation.

I remember reading once that `GROUP BY NULL` have the same meaning. Is it correct? Otherwise what would `GROUP BY NULL` mean ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aggregating by () is the same thing that aggregating for no value, or for a constant value.
For example:

```
create table test_group(cod varchar2(16), descr varchar2(16), num number);
insert into test_group values ('a', 'letter A', 10);
insert into test_group values ('b', 'letter b', 20);
insert into test_group values ('b', 'letter B', 35);
insert into test_group values ('c', 'letter c', 70);
insert into test_group values ('c', 'letter c', 99);
```

Aggregation by no value

```
SQL> select sum(num)
  2  from test_group;

  SUM(NUM)
----------
       234
```

Aggregation by `null`

```
SQL> select sum(num)
  2  from test_group
  3  group by null;

  SUM(NUM)
----------
       234
```

Aggregation by `()`:

```
SQL> select sum(num)
  2  from test_group
  3  group by ();

  SUM(NUM)
----------
       234
```

Aggregation by a constant value:

```
SQL> select sum(num)
  2  from test_group
  3  group by 'constant';

  SUM(NUM)
----------
       234
```

You have to explicitly write your aggregation condition:

```
SQL> select *
  2  from test_group
  3  group by *;
group by *
         *
ERROR at line 3:
ORA-00936: missing expression
```